# write only stream

Tags: event-sourcing, neventstore

I'm using joliver/EventStore library and trying to find a way of how to get a stream not reading any events from it.

The reason is that I want just to write some events into that store for specific stream without loading all 10k messages from it.

Comment: And you're sure you're not in a snapshotting case ? (prob not - its def not a must-do...)

Comment: I'm not using snapshots, just wanted submit an event

Comment: OK, but is 10,000 events a common case for you? (I'm not saying your question is unreasonable, just asking have you considered / are you in a situation where the number of events is going to push you into snapshotting anyway). (One reason I ask/mention this is that the standard `GetById` mechanisms consult the snapshot cache first, which is in the direction you are looking. As for the actual answer to your question, I'm guessing it's a no, but I'd have to look at the source to be sure.

Comment: it's just looks weird: why should I query for any data if I want to just insert one event into store? I'm not doing dispatching at the moment, messages will be dispatched by another application.

Comment: Not talking about dispatching. I personally have never had a desire / requirement for this. Typically anything that's going to Raise an event will first be doing validation or deduplication for the purposes of making Commands idempotent etc. Generally a blind write like this suggests a queue. Anyway, +1 on the question....

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean and thank you for pointing that out. I have all sorts of events and one of them is just "app started" type of event which does not require any prior validation. For such events I could probably create new stream each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're expected to use the store is that you always do a `GetById` first. Even if you new up an Aggregate and `Save` it, you'll see in the CommonDomain `EventStoreRepository` that it will first correlate it with the existing data.

The key reason why a read is needed first is that the infrastructure needs to work out how many events have gone before to compute the new commit sequence number.

Regarding your citing of your example threshold that makes you want to optimize this away... If you're really going to have that level of events, you'll already be into snapshotting territory as you'll need to have an appropriately efficient way of doing things other than blind write too.

Even if you're not intending to lean on snapshotting, half the benefit of using `EventStore` is that the facility is buitl in for when you need it.

Comment: Thank you Ruben, now it's more clear to me. I've ended up with creating my own event storage without revision numbers, but only time stamps. Looks like right now I don't need all goodness that EventStore library provides. As for aggregates - I'll probably go with relational database. "magic number" was obviously faked just to illustrate my concerns.

Comment: @ILICH Good to hear you're arriving in a useful place. Just to clarify my use of the word Aggregate... This is referring to the notion that the Event Store is a tool for the modelling of Event Sourced Aggregate objects in a domain layer. One critical thing about the Event Store is that it does *not* assume the storage will be an Aggregate-based store (I and others happen to use a SQL database for the Event Storage side, without using the relational facilities) so whether or not you're using a relational database should not be the decider. BTW I highly recommend reading NoSql Distilled